# Get rid of redundant cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.Boolean> warning from CXF-generated code

Tags: java, compiler-construction, warnings, cxf

I generate some code using [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/) from a WSDL-file. When compiling the code with version "1.6.0_16" with the flag -Xlint I get the following warning:

```
warning: [cast] redundant cast to javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<java.lang.Boolean>
   [javac]         this.r = ((JAXBElement<Boolean> ) value);
```

What does the warning mean, should I be worried? As I have generated and not written the code, what can I do to get rid of this specific warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you should not be worried, redundant casts are harmless.

It's common for generated code to compile with warnings, you generally just ignore them.  Better yet, compile the generated code into a separate JAR, and reference that from your main code. That way, you don't need to recompile the generated code, and you won't see the warnings every time.

Comment: They may be harmless, and the advice to ignore them is good. But it's hard to understand why such pointlessly redundant code would be generated in the first place. It's not a matter of being backwards compatible or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem while CXF was generating code **redundant cast to byte[]** while **-Werror** and **-Xlint:all** was set in maven to compile the code

A possible workaround for me/us was to add:

**-Xlint:-cast** to suppress the warning and keep the -Werror flag